Should I have more than one websocket per user?
I have an application that has real-time notification functionality. To do this, I implement websockets together with Redis Pub/Sub. This is the current design:

So each user is subscribed to several redis channels (from the backend, then the backend sends this information to the frontend). Some channels have few posts and others more frequently, the issue is that since you are subscribed to many channels, there are times when, for example, 8-10 messages per second arrive at the backend. Should I have 2 websocket connections open (one for infrequent channels and others for those who publish more frequently) or is this loading not a problem and should I have one websocket per client?

FWIW, I don't see how having multiple client<->backend ws connections would buy you anything.

at the end, all the messages would be served by the Bcckend and reach the client, so adding another connection won't be helpful, in contrary there is a limit of concurrent connections on the server so unless you see a problem (I don't think there would be) you better not add new connections
